# MySQLi Object-oriented redirect depending on user role

Tags: php, mysql, oop, authentication, mysqli

Can't figure out where my error is, I want to redirect to different sections of the website depending on the user role.

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE email = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {       
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            if ($row['role']=='admin') {
                header('Location: admin.php');
            } else if ($row['role']=='user') {
                header('Location: profile.php');
            }
        } else {
            $password_incorrect = '¡Contraseña incorrecta! Si has olvidado tu contraseña puedes <a href="#">restablecerla</a>.';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not selecting the `role` column in your query, so you can never check against that value. You're also using `store_result()`, but keep some of the statement approach. Recommend you stay to one or the other (this code removes `store_result()` and just uses plain prepared statements).

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, password, role FROM accounts WHERE email = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $role);

    if ($stmt->fetch() && password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {       
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

        if ($role == 'admin') {
            header('Location: admin.php');
            exit;
        } elseif ($role == 'user') {
            header('Location: profile.php');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $password_incorrect = '¡Contraseña incorrecta! Si has olvidado tu contraseña puedes <a href="#">restablecerla</a>.';
    }
}
```